# How to put a ListView and a RecyclerView in a CoordinatorLayout and drag the boundary between them

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a calendar widget that displays months which extends ListView (Square's Time-Square)
Below I have the schedule of the user for the selected day, in a Recycler View.

The interaction is described in the image. I have no idea how to implement this. I think I need to use CoordinatorLayout but I am not sure how.

[image]

Edit: I just managed to do it, but it turns out ListView doesnt support Nested Scrolling so I had to riskily rewrite the Square TimeSquare class from a ListView to RecyclerView. Then I fiddled about with some code I found here: https://github.com/bherbst/QuickReturnFooterSample/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml and I kinda achieved the effect I was looking for